# Deserialize XML and get value using Java

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot

When I use a distance API I get this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1">
    <Copyright>Copyright © 2020 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.</Copyright>
    <BrandLogoUri>http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png</BrandLogoUri>
    <StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
    <StatusDescription>OK</StatusDescription>
    <AuthenticationResultCode>ValidCredentials</AuthenticationResultCode>
    <TraceId>df8ee9b6422846f0b97644c0a631deb8|DU00000D71|0.0.0.0|DU000005EC, DU00000480|Ref A: F00DC0285E97417B99490A8C98E65E31 Ref B: DB3EDGE1608 Ref C: 2020-06-09T18:53:54Z|Ref A: 69E0F633DF6448A89B2B904773DF19AB Ref B: DB3EDGE0807 Ref C: 2020-06-09T18:53:54Z</TraceId>
    <ResourceSets>
        <ResourceSet>
            <EstimatedTotal>1</EstimatedTotal>
            <Resources>
                <Route>
                    <Id>v69,h1509963868,i0,a2,cen-US,dAAAAAAAAAAA1,y0,s1,m1,o1,t4,wWriswmZmQkBa9bnail0kQA2~BFnWzEBwiKgBBH_gASHtAT8A0~VHVuaXMsIFR1bmlzaWE1~~~~v11,w-Ki_XmFfQUC94xQdyYUlQA2~BFnWzEBYRLoBBH_gAc1znT4B0~U2ZheCwgVHVuaXNpYQ2~~~~v11,k1</Id>
                    <BoundingBox>
                        <SouthLatitude>34.74499</SouthLatitude>
                        <WestLongitude>10.18235</WestLongitude>
                        <NorthLatitude>36.800014</NorthLatitude>
                        <EastLongitude>10.76493</EastLongitude>
                    </BoundingBox>
                    <DistanceUnit>Kilometer</DistanceUnit>
                    <DurationUnit>Second</DurationUnit>
                    <TravelDistance>271.101</TravelDistance>
                    ...
```

I want to get the value of `TravelDistance`.

If possible a full code because I have been trying with this for long time and no solution.

Comment: Generate a Java class representing the XML document. It's entirely likely that this already exists as a dependency (look at the docs for the service you're using); if not, the `xmlns` provides the schema that you can use to generate the class.

Comment: yeah that is my problem i could not know what type of class to put data in. can you give more details about how to use the xmlns for schema or maybe refer me to some resources?

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `XmlMapper` of `jackson` to de/serialize your XML.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

so you shall need to create an instance of it and deserialize as follows :

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
Response value = xmlMapper.readValue("<Response>..</Response>", Response.class);
```

So you will need to create your object model that reflects your XML.

```
public class Response {
    private String Copyright;
    private String BrandLogoUri;
    private String StatusCode;
    private String StatusDescription;
    private String AuthenticationResultCode;
    private String TraceId;
    ResourceSets ResourceSetsObject;


    // Getter Methods 

    public String getCopyright() {
        return Copyright;
    }

    public String getBrandLogoUri() {
        return BrandLogoUri;
    }

    public String getStatusCode() {
        return StatusCode;
    }

    public String getStatusDescription() {
        return StatusDescription;
    }

    public String getAuthenticationResultCode() {
        return AuthenticationResultCode;
    }

    public String getTraceId() {
        return TraceId;
    }

    public ResourceSets getResourceSets() {
        return ResourceSetsObject;
    }

    // Setter Methods 

    public void setCopyright(String Copyright) {
        this.Copyright = Copyright;
    }

    public void setBrandLogoUri(String BrandLogoUri) {
        this.BrandLogoUri = BrandLogoUri;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(String StatusCode) {
        this.StatusCode = StatusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusDescription(String StatusDescription) {
        this.StatusDescription = StatusDescription;
    }

    public void setAuthenticationResultCode(String AuthenticationResultCode) {
        this.AuthenticationResultCode = AuthenticationResultCode;
    }

    public void setTraceId(String TraceId) {
        this.TraceId = TraceId;
    }

    public void setResourceSets(ResourceSets ResourceSetsObject) {
        this.ResourceSetsObject = ResourceSetsObject;
    }
}
public class ResourceSets {
    ResourceSet ResourceSetObject;


    // Getter Methods 

    public ResourceSet getResourceSet() {
        return ResourceSetObject;
    }

    // Setter Methods 

    public void setResourceSet(ResourceSet ResourceSetObject) {
        this.ResourceSetObject = ResourceSetObject;
    }
}
public class ResourceSet {
    private String EstimatedTotal;
    Resources ResourcesObject;


    // Getter Methods 

    public String getEstimatedTotal() {
        return EstimatedTotal;
    }

    public Resources getResources() {
        return ResourcesObject;
    }

    // Setter Methods 

    public void setEstimatedTotal(String EstimatedTotal) {
        this.EstimatedTotal = EstimatedTotal;
    }

    public void setResources(Resources ResourcesObject) {
        this.ResourcesObject = ResourcesObject;
    }
}
public class Resources {
    Route RouteObject;


    // Getter Methods 

    public Route getRoute() {
        return RouteObject;
    }

    // Setter Methods 

    public void setRoute(Route RouteObject) {
        this.RouteObject = RouteObject;
    }
}
public class Route {
    private String Id;
    BoundingBox BoundingBoxObject;
    private String DistanceUnit;
    private String DurationUnit;
    private String TravelDistance;


    // Getter Methods 

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public BoundingBox getBoundingBox() {
        return BoundingBoxObject;
    }

    public String getDistanceUnit() {
        return DistanceUnit;
    }

    public String getDurationUnit() {
        return DurationUnit;
    }

    public String getTravelDistance() {
        return TravelDistance;
    }

    // Setter Methods 

    public void setId(String Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public void setBoundingBox(BoundingBox BoundingBoxObject) {
        this.BoundingBoxObject = BoundingBoxObject;
    }

    public void setDistanceUnit(String DistanceUnit) {
        this.DistanceUnit = DistanceUnit;
    }

    public void setDurationUnit(String DurationUnit) {
        this.DurationUnit = DurationUnit;
    }

    public void setTravelDistance(String TravelDistance) {
        this.TravelDistance = TravelDistance;
    }
}
public class BoundingBox {
    private String SouthLatitude;
    private String WestLongitude;
    private String NorthLatitude;
    private String EastLongitude;


    // Getter Methods 

    public String getSouthLatitude() {
        return SouthLatitude;
    }

    public String getWestLongitude() {
        return WestLongitude;
    }

    public String getNorthLatitude() {
        return NorthLatitude;
    }

    public String getEastLongitude() {
        return EastLongitude;
    }

    // Setter Methods 

    public void setSouthLatitude(String SouthLatitude) {
        this.SouthLatitude = SouthLatitude;
    }

    public void setWestLongitude(String WestLongitude) {
        this.WestLongitude = WestLongitude;
    }

    public void setNorthLatitude(String NorthLatitude) {
        this.NorthLatitude = NorthLatitude;
    }

    public void setEastLongitude(String EastLongitude) {
        this.EastLongitude = EastLongitude;
    }
}
```